# Custom Keycodes

Tags: java, android

This may have been asked but I cant seem to find anything about this. Is there a way for me to edit the R.attr file and add in custom KeyCodes? There is nothing being used at number 275 and up, for now I am using the random ones that are rarely used to accomplish what I want but it might conflict some day so I would like to just make my own constants.

Comment: Are you making a custom ROM?

Comment: No this is for a custom keyboard app.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way for me to edit the R.attr file and add in custom KeyCodes?

No. `R.attr` is a Java class in the Android SDK. While you are welcome to hack your own copy of `android.jar` to define whatever you want, that will have no impact whatsoever on the rest of the Android ecosystem: users, app developers, device manufacturers, or Google.

For example, just because you, in your own hard drive's copy of the compiled `R.attr` bytecode, have defined a new keycode named `KEYCODE_CHON_BON`, with a value of 1337, that means effectively nothing:

- No developers will have `KEYCODE_CHON_BON` in their SDKs and so cannot code to it by that symbol, and few (if any) will know (or care) to code to looking for 1337 as a literal value
- The device can still use 1337 for its own purposes (e.g., manufacturer-specific special key)
- Google can still use 1337 in some future version of Android

You are welcome to create a custom ROM, then having people install that custom ROM. This would ensure that only those keycodes that you want are going to be generated by that ROM, and so you do not have to worry about manufacturers or Google going in and electing to use keycodes that conflict with yours.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation, at first this thought totally went over my head then after a bit of thinking I realized it might be locally based like you said with each individual SDK on each phone.I wonder if there is a way to include a java class that I can make to simulate these keycodes and similar actions. Probably not, oh well, I will continue to do what I am doing.